# Is it allowed to use any decimal value in CSS keyframe animations?

Tags: css, percentage, css-animations

I'm wondering if it's ok to use percentage values like this:

```
@keyframes myAnimation {
    0%    { height: 100px; }
    33.3% { height: 120px; }
    66.6% { height: 140px; }
    100%  { height: 200px; }
}
```

It seems to work, but it I am not sure if the browsers might just "round" this? And what about values like 33.3457%?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, let's say you have an animation that runs for 1000 seconds. 33% of that are 330 seconds while 33.3% are 333 seconds. That's a difference of 3 seconds, so yes, it does matter.

Comment: I added this previous comment because the editor of this question asked "if it matters" and then deleted his comment after I answered. I don't know why he did that, but I don't want to leave my comment here without any context...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

When it comes to CSS it takes notice of percentages down to 2 decimal places and then stops. So you would be able to get 33.34% but not 33.3457% for use in your keyframes

I hope this helps.

Comment: I can't find any text in [the CSS animations specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/) that says that the percentages are valid to only two decimal places. Care to point it out?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can use more than 2 decimal spaces. For example, Twitter Bootstrap uses 8 decimal points on their percentages, and while I don't know for sure I doubt that they would do that unless there was a reason for it.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can use fractional part to define more precise keyframes percentages. But such precision is [not clearly specified](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#keyframes).

It's supported by all browsers that support CSS animations. But don't use too much decimals, strange behaviour may occur (especially above 5 digits).

I use that for complex animations with loops :

```
@keyframes{
    0%, 30%, 40%, 50%, 60%{
        top: 0px;
    }
    29.99999%, 39.99999%, 49.99999%, 59.99999%{
        top: 100px;
    }
    100%{
        top: 200px;
    }
}
/*
- 0px to 100px (30%)
- loop 3 times 0px to 100px (10% each, total 30%)
- 0px to 200px (40%)
*/
```

The SASS default precision is 3 digits and can be changed with `--precision` (cmd option) or `Sass::Script::Number.precision`