# Can you use more than a whole number with @keyframe percents?

Tags: css, animation

I have a large animation with smaller parts so that it can repeat infinitely.

```
@-webkit-keyframes doubletap {
  0% {opacity: 0;}
  11% {opacity: 0;}
  12.6% {opacity: 1;}
  15.625% {opacity: 0;}
  18.65% {opacity: 1;}
  18.75% {opacity: 0;}
  94% {opacity: 0;}
  95%{opacity: 1}
  97.5%{opacity: 0;}
  99%{opacity: 1;}
  100% {opacity: 0;}
}
```

would it be read as those percents exactly or does it round to the nearest full number or ignore the decimal altogether? It says nothing about this on MDN or anywhere else I can find.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it allowed to use any decimal value in CSS keyframe animations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486242/is-it-allowed-to-use-any-decimal-value-in-css-keyframe-animations)

Comment: Sorry, I searched for that almost verbatim but didn't find anything. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

CSS  takes notice of percentages down to 2 decimal places and then stops. So you would be able to get 18.65% but not 15.625% for use in your keyframes

Comment: Thank you, I see now there is another question similar to mine, thank you for answering anyway.