# CSS Keyframes: How to integrate step rotate with linear rotate

Tags: css, animation, rotation, transform, keyframe

```
@keyframes spinner-spin
  0%
    transform: rotate(0deg)
  24.99999%
    transform: rotate(90deg)
  25%
    transform: rotate(270deg)
  49.99999%
    transform: rotate(360deg)
  50%
    transform: rotate(180deg)
  74.99999%
    transform: rotate(270deg)
  75%
    transform: rotate(90deg)
  99.99999%
    transform: rotate(180deg)
  100%
    transform: rotate(360deg)
```

Right now I am doing something really hacky. The reason is because I need to do something like a "step" every 25%. I can't seem to apply a second "step" animation to do additional rotation, because the rotations don't stack, they just take over. What is a more reliable solution to apply an additional -90deg rotation step every 25%?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it allowed to use any decimal value in CSS keyframe animations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486242/is-it-allowed-to-use-any-decimal-value-in-css-keyframe-animations)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that.. Just updated my question :)